# Is possible to use NullPool instead of QueuePool when using z3c.saconfig?

Tags: plone, zope

I have a Zope / Plone 4.3 environment and we use `z3c.saconfig` to configure the database (Oracle) settings in a internal product.

I need to change the usual SQLAlchemy's pool type from `QueuePool` to `NullPool`. But, is there a way to do it using `z3c.saconfig`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`z3c.saconfig` delegates creating the SQLAlchemy engine to a `IEngineFactory` utility; see the [interface source](https://github.com/do3cc/zope/blob/master/z3c.saconfig/trunk/src/z3c/saconfig/interfaces.py#L33-L58).

You can create your own subclass of it to register as a [local utility](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/utilities.html#registering-a-local-utility). Your subclass could reuse the existing utility implementation, overriding the [`configuration()` method](https://github.com/do3cc/zope/blob/master/z3c.saconfig/trunk/src/z3c/saconfig/utility.py#L171-L177):

```
from persistent import Persistent
from z3c.saconfig.utility import EngineFactory
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

class NullPoolEngineFactory(Persistent, EngineFactory)
    def configuration(self):
        kwargs = self._kw.copy()
        kwargs['poolclass'] = NullPool
        return self._args, kwargs
```

The above augments the arguments for the `sqlalchemy.create_engine()` function by adding a [`poolclass` argument](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.create_engine.params.poolclass).

You'd register this utility as a component in your GenericSetup profile:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<componentregistry>
  <utilities>
    <utility
        interface="z3c.saconfig.interfaces.IEngineFactory"
        factory="yourproject.yourmodule.NullPoolEngineFactory"/>
  </utilities>
</componentregistry>
```

After running your generic setup profile, this registers a persistent version of the utility, and it'll be found instead of the default global utility.